# Angular2 component - function not being recognised

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying to create a separate component to deal with the presentation of a news feed. It works fine when I have everything within app.component.ts, but when I separate the code into its own component (news-feed.component.ts) it initially displays fine but when a menu button is clicked (e.g.: `<button (click)="getNews('the-telegraph')">telegraph</button>`) it is failing to recognise the function 'getNews' and the following error is generated:'**EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:4:12 caused by: self.context.getNews is not a function**'.

Please note - it is successfully running the getNews() function within the NewsFeedComponent when the site first loads.

Here is app.component.ts:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NewsService} from './news.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { NewsFeedComponent }  from './news-feed.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'news-app',
  template:`
  <h1>News Feed</h1>
  <nav>
    <button (click)="getNews('bbc-news')">bbc</button>
    <button (click)="getNews('the-telegraph')">telegraph</button>
    <button (click)="getNews('the-guardian-uk')">guardian</button>
    <button (click)="getNews('independent')">independent</button>
    <button (click)="getNews('financial-times')">financial times</button>
    <button (click)="getNews('the-economist')">the economist</button>
    <button (click)="getNews('sky-news')">sky news</button>
    <button (click)="getNews('the-new-york-times')">the new york times</button>
  </nav>
  <news-feed></news-feed>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Here is news-feed.component.ts:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NewsService} from './news.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'

@Component({
  selector: 'news-feed',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let article of news">
      hello2
        <a href="{{article.url}}" target="_bank"><h2>{{article.title}}</h2></a>
        <p>{{article.publishedAt}}</p>
        <img src="{{article.urlToImage}}" style="width: 200px;">
        <p>{{article.description}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class NewsFeedComponent {
  // public news;

  constructor(private _newsService: NewsService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getNews('bbc-news');
  }

  getNews(source) {
    this._newsService.getNews(source).subscribe(
      // the first argument is a function which runs on success
      data => { 
        this.news = data['articles']
      },
       error => {
         //console.error("Error saving food!");
         return Observable.throw(error);
       }
    );
  }
}
```

Here is app.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {NewsService} from './news.service'

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

import { NewsFeedComponent }  from './news-feed.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,HttpModule,FormsModule],
    declarations: [
     AppComponent,
     NewsFeedComponent
      ],
    providers: [NewsService],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Apologies for cutting and pasting in all this code. I have tried to get this working on Plunker and have failed due to being very stupid. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure but try adding this in your module: import { NewsFeedComponent }  from './news-feed.component';

Comment: You are calling `getNews` method inside app components template but your method is inside your child component.

Comment: The `getNews` is expected on your `AppComponent ` class, because it is **outside** your `news-feed`

Answer (score 2):

As commented at the question by @echonax and @devqon, you are calling `getNews` from `AppComponent` which is defined in your child component `NewsFeedComponent`. If this is the problem, try to move the function `getNews` to the AppComponent.

---

And, If you just want to call a child component's function, you can do it this way.

```
<nav>
  <button (click)="newsFeed.getNews('bbc-news')">bbc</button>
  // all the same
</nav>
<news-feed #newsFeed></news-feed>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this and it now works. You have made a very stupid man very happy. You have no idea how long I have struggled with this!

Comment: @Stupid Glad that you make through it. And  if this answered you, don't forget to mark it as an answer to let others easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling `getNews` function from your `AppComponent` html(as `getNews` isn't available in its context). Rather what you should be doing is, on click of button you should set some variable as like `feedType = 'bbc-news'` and pass it as input binding to your `news-feed`.

There it will receive type of feed dynamically using `@Input` binding and you can call the `getNews` method with selected appropriate `feedType`

```
<h1>News Feed</h1>
<nav>
    <button (click)="feedType = 'bbc-news'">bbc</button>
    <button (click)="feedType = 'the-telegraph'">telegraph</button>
    <button (click)="feedType = 'the-guardian-uk'">guardian</button>
    <button (click)="feedType = 'independent'">independent</button>
    <button (click)="feedType = 'financial-times'">financial times</button>
    <button (click)="feedType = 'the-economist'">the economist</button>
    <button (click)="feedType = 'sky-news'">sky news</button>
    <button (click)="feedType = 'the-new-york-times'">the new york times</button>
</nav>
<news-feed [feedType]="feedType"></news-feed>
```

Then add `Input` property binding in `news-feed` component

```
@Input() feedType;
constructor(private _newsService: NewsService) { }
//call getNews with selected `feedType`
ngOnInit() {
    this.getNews(this.feedType);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Very clear answer. I will experiment with implementing this also.